# JFrogArtifactoryDeployer - The string is missing the terminator: '

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory

I am using the JFrogArtifactoryDeployer plugin as part of a build definition in VS Team Services. When the build gets to this plugin it throws the following message:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: JFrogArtifactoryDeployer
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : JFrog Artifactory Deployer
Description  :  This task helps you to deploy generic build result artifacts to Artifactory
Version      : 2.1.1
Author       : jfrog
Help         : Upload artifacts to JFrog Artifactory using JFrog Artifactory cli.
==============================================================================
Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\JFrogArtifactoryDeployer_07fc5c20-
6772-11e5-abde-6901d3d00465\2.1.1\ArtifactoryDeploy.ps1
Entering JFrog Artifactory Deployer task
Import modules
Downloading the JFrog cli from Bintray
running 'C:\agent\_work\13\a\jfrog.exe' rt upload 'C:\\agent\\_work\\13\\a\\ArtifactoryUpload
\\*.nupkg' 'nuget/Project-R2/' --url=http://artifactory.local:8081/artifactory --user=********
 --password=******** --props='build.number=1.1.0.3-R2-11367;build.name=R2-CI-CD-JFrogIntegrationTesting'
System.Management.Automation.ParseException: At line:1 char:322
+ ... .number=1.1.0.3-R2-11367;build.name=R2-CI-CD-JFrogIntegrationTesting'
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(Parser parser, String fileName, String fileContents)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(ExecutionContext context, String script)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandInvocationIntrinsics.NewScriptBlock(String scriptText)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Deployment to Artifactory failed
PowerShell script completed with 2 errors.
******************************************************************************
Finishing: JFrogArtifactoryDeployer
******************************************************************************
```

Has anyone encountered this error with this plugin?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, try to set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then post the detail log here or share it on the OneDrive. On the other hand, try to create a new repository and try again.

Comment: Do you have a ' character in the password? If yes, change the password and then try again.

Comment: Looks like my password does contain a ' character in it. I am going to change the password and try again.

Comment: Also a general good practice would be tu use you Artifactory api key instead of clear text password (or at least encrypted password)

Comment: What's the result after changing password?

Comment: Changing the password corrected the problem. Ideally we would be using an apikey, but we ran into some issues with it that we are working through.